# Some Patriotic Steganography

Tags: steganography, poetry

> Say there, American soldier, sir.
>
> Stay there, good mister, and answer a question.
>
> Where do you go, and why do you go,
>
> Dragging your load through the cold, wet, mud?
>
> We thank you for your service, though we don't know the cost.
>
> We thank you for your life, as you keep safe ours.
>
> We give one such as you no true gift in return,
>
> Us, we can give only our gratitude - and pity - and scorn.
>
> We try, we try to salute you, but
>
> O Republicans and Democrats, Liberals and Conservatives:
>
> You claim to possess a love for our nation, but
>
> What on earth have you given, and expended, and released
>
> That a soldier, your tool, has not already given to you?

Just thought I'd throw a little gratitude for my country's soldiers into this puzzle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure this is the full answer, but

> if you remove spaces and punctuation and take the first letter of the first line, second letter of the second line, etc

you get

> Steganography

i.e.

> **S**aythereAmericansoldiersir.
>  S**T**aytheregoodmisterandansweraquestion.
>  Wh**E**redoyougoandwhydoyougo
>  Dra**G**gingyourloadthroughthecoldwetmud?
>  Weth**A**nkyouforyourservicethoughwedon'tknowthecost.
>  Wetha**N**kyouforyourlifeasyoukeepsafeours.
>  Wegive**O**nesuchasyounotruegiftinreturn
>  Uswecan**G**iveonlyourgratitude-andpity-andscorn.
>  WetryWet**R**ytosaluteyoubut
>  ORepublic**A**nsandDemocratsLiberalsandConservatives:
>  Youclaimto**P**ossessaloveforournationbut
>  Whatonearth**H**aveyougivenandexpendedandreleased
>  Thatasoldier**Y**ourtoolhasnotalreadygiventoyou?

Comment: Good solve! That is the correct answer.